# How to find max in list of lists?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have the following list:

```
[[2016, 'May', 16.9],
 [2016, 'April', 17.5],
 [2016, 'March', 17.8],
 [2016, 'February', 18.6],
 [2016, 'January', 18.8],
 [2015, 'December', 19.1],
 [2015, 'November', 19.2],
 [2015, 'October', 20.0],
 [2015, 'September', 20.6],
 [2015, 'August', 21.2],
 [2015, 'July', 21.6],
 [2015, 'June', 21.3],
 [2015, 'May', 21.5],
 [2015, 'April', 21.6],
 [2015, 'March', 22.1]]
```

I would like to get back the list as in `[2015, 'March', 22.1]`, for where the last element is the highest out of the entire list.

What would be a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using builtin `max` function with proper lambda.

```
max(data, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(llist, key= lambda x: x[2])[-1]
```

where llist is your list.